# How to use a whitelist with grep

Tags: grep, whitelist

I have a list of email addresses. I also have a list of common first and last names. I want to filter the email list against the one with common first and last names, thus only printing emails with either a common first and / or last name in the output file.

So, I tried:

```
cat file | egrep -e -i < whitelist | tee emails_with_common_first_and_last_names.txt
```

At first, this seemed like it was working. Then, after examining the output, it did not seem to do anything.

```
wc -l input output
```

This revealed that nothing was filtered.

So, how else can I do this or what am I doing incorrectly?

Here is a sample of the file that I would like filtered:

```
aynz@falskdf.com
8zlkhsdf0@fmail.com
afjsg@domain.com
```

Here is a sample of the whitelist that I would like to use as a reference to filer the file:

```
ALEX
johnson
WINTERS
miles
christina
tonya
jackson
schmidt
jake
```

So, if an email contains any of these, grep or whatever needs to print it to a output file.

Comment: You can't feed `egrep` input from two places at once. It either reads from the pipe **or** from the redirected file. (You don't have two standard inputs.) Are you trying to search in `file` for any line that matches the content of the lines in `whitelist`?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I just added a sample for @Cyrus.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I added a sample to clarify.

Comment: ... and what is your desired output for that sample input?

Comment: `grep -Fwf whitelist file`?

Comment: My desired output would be to only print the emails that contain one or more of those names in a text file with a \n delimiter.